# Can't get PHP Command Line Script to execute without prepending 'php' despite shebang added and path to symlinked executable added to PATH

Tags: php, bash, symfony, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create something similar to the laravel installer, it's a PHP Script that utilises Symfony's Console Component. It all works fine except I can't seem to get the damn thing to execute globally on my command line.

I've currently got the script(boiler) stored as /dir/dir/vendor/author/packagename/boiler.

Via Composer I also have a symlink that points to the script from /dir/dir/vendor/bin/. Automatically done via bin in composer.json.

I've updated my $PATH, which now shows /folder/folder/vendor/bin/ to point to the symlink;

My script starts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Permissions are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

I'm running Zshell on Mac OSX.

---

It will run if I go into the directory and type `php boiler` but `boiler`returns command not found and if I'm in a different directory `boiler` also returns command not found. `php boiler` returns "Could not open input file: boiler"

The laravel installer runs exactly as I want mine to, using just laravel whilst anywhere on the command line.

At a complete loss. Google isn't turning up any similar issues, and neither is Stack (My searching ability may be lacking though, it's 4am.)

Comment: Is the symlink correct? What is the output of `ls -l /folder/folder/vendor/bin/boiler`? Also, consider posting the output of `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Have you tried running the script from the same directory using `./boiler`

Comment: @Cyclone ./boiler works.

Comment: @KMountford - Then it sounds like there is simply something wrong with the symlink or how your `$PATH` is setup.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Have double checked and the symlink is correct. ls -l results in 'lrwxr-xr-x  1 KMountford  staff  31 24 Jan 03:46 dir/dir/vendor/bin/boiler -> ../author/packagename/boiler'

Comment: $PATH returns /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/kirrynmountford/.composer/vendor/bin:/Users/kirrynmountford/Code/Packages/vendor/bin

Users/kirrynmountford/Code/Packages/vendor/bin is where the symlink is.

Comment: The target of the symlink should be `../author/packagename/script/boiler`, according to the text in your question.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Sorry, that was me referring to the script as script rather than boiler not a directory called script.

Comment: What happens if you try `cat /dir/dir/vendor/bin/boiler`?

Comment: You can check if it's in your path with `which boiler`.

Comment: `which boiler` returned the correct path so I tried `boiler` again from my home dir and it worked. I genuinely haven't changed a single thing and been stuck for an hour. I don't understand... Thank you all for your help.

Comment: perhaps you had to restart your terminal for this to take effect?

Comment: @Cyclone Had done that multiple times too with `echo $PATH` showing the correct path listed as above.

Comment: Very strange. Nice you got it working though.

Answer (score 0):

For those with similar issues:

- Use `which commandName` to see if it's correctly added to your $PATH
- Check the symlink is correct if it's via one
- Check permissions on symlink and executable script
- Post to stackoverflow so that it'll just.. fix itself.

---

So... `which boiler` returned the correct path so I tried `boiler` again from my home dir and it worked.

I genuinely haven't changed a single thing and been stuck for an hour. I don't understand...

Thanks all for help.